# Snowflake: Convert arrays of keys and values to an object

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal is to combine two input arrays to an [OBJECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured#object):

For:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(keys ARRAY, vals ARRAY) AS
SELECT ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'], [1,2,3] UNION ALL
SELECT ['keyA', 'keyB'], ['a','b'];
```

| KEYS | VALS | DESIRED_OUTPUT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [ "key1", "key2", "key3" ] | [ 1, 2, 3 ] | { "key1": 1, "key2": 2, "key3": 3 } |
| [ "keyA", "keyB" ] | [ "a", "b" ] | { "keyA": "a", "keyB": "b" } |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to achieve it with the [ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/arrays_to_object) function.

```
SHOW BUILTIN FUNCTIONS LIKE 'ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT';
-- arguments 
-- ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT(ARRAY, ARRAY) RETURN OBJECT
```

Query:

```
SELECT *, ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT(keys, vals)
FROM tab;
```

Output:

[image]

---

It can also be used as an alternative to [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct):

```
SELECT id
      ,ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT(['col1', 'col2'], [col1, col2])
      ,OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('col1', col1, 'col2', col2)
FROM VALUES (1, 'a', 'b'), (2, 'x', 'y') AS s(id, col1, col2);
```

Output:

```
ID  ARRAYS_TO_OBJECT(['COL1', 'COL2'], [COL1, COL2])    OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('COL1', COL1, 'COL2', COL2)
1   {   "col1": "a",   "col2": "b" }                    {   "col1": "a",   "col2": "b" }
2   {   "col1": "x",   "col2": "y" }                    {   "col1": "x",   "col2": "y" }
```